# how to use custom log4j jar dependency in glassfish

Tags: java, maven, glassfish, log4j

I am new to Glassfish and Maven.

I have a custom log4j(custom_log4j.jar) which is extend existing log4j.jar with some add-on features. The problem is how can I config my maven or glassfish to use my custom_log4j.jar instead of accessing the standard log4j.jar.

I have try to to find out on the internet, some says have to put this custom_log4j.jar into galssfish/domains1/lib/ext, some says put to galssfish/domains1/lib. Which is correct? And how can I config in pom.xml to access this custom_log4j.jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been dig into this for a day and finally got it. Here it is:

First of all put this custom jar under *glassfish\domains\domain1\lib\ext*
and then config this in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>custom_log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>custom_log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>  
           <systemPath>C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib\ext\custom_log4j.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

However, if you project requires brunch of those custom dependencies, better setup your nexus for all those dependencies.